# Unordered_map keys changed after iteration?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I am debugging a program like this:

```
    int findPairs(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    int res=0;
    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    for(auto num:nums) ++m[num];
    for(auto const& a:m) cout<<"("<<a.first<<" "<<a.second<<")"<<endl;
    for(auto const& a:m) cout<<a.first<<endl;
    for(auto const&a:m){
        cout<<a.first<<endl;
        //cout<<a.first+k<<" "<<m[a.first+k]<<endl;
        if(k==0 && a.second>1) ++res;
        if(k>0 && m[a.first+k]) ++res;
    }

    return res;

}
```

k=2, nums={3,1,4,1,5}

But the cout output is suprising:

(5 1)

(4 1)

(3 1)

(1 2)

5

4

3

1

5

4

5

7

0(return status)

After one iteration, how can latter two keys increased by 2?

Comment: `[]` on a map, will insert the key if it's not found. Also, don't modify a container as you are iterating over it.

Comment: `m[a.first+k]` inserts the key if it doesn't exist in the map yet (happens for values 4 and 5). This happens inside the `for` loop that's iterating over `m`. Modifying a map that you're iterating over is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Look at iterator invalidation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map the `operator[]` will invalidate your iterator if it causes a rehash. I guess you could insert while iterating if you knew what you were doing, but I'd avoid it as a best practice.

Comment: Instead of checking with `m[a.first+k]`, you may use `find()`. `find()` may return `end()` if key is not found. However, it won't change the map.